# rails how to generate a http link connect to some path without knowing current domain at backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example,  I dont know my website name yet, it can be www.abc.com or www.xyz.com

And I want to send a email to my users with the link

```
www.abc.com/controller1/id/path
or
www.xyz.com/controller1/id/path
```

How I setup this on rails ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter what the hostname of your app is when using the right helper, rails will generate either relative paths or absolute paths for links at runtime (depending on the helper used). [url_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) is one such helper, [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is another. Any route that is defined in routes.rb, you get a helper for it. Try looking at the output from `rake routes`, you'll see which url helpers may already be defined. Just add `_path` to the routes you see listed in the first column to get a relative path url.  For more info on routing see the [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).